# Can rest service return .Net Object

Tags: rest, object, service, client

I have a  client application developed in java. This application consumes rest web service developed in .Net platform.

Rest web service uses our product API to provide respective functionalities to client application. Rest web service uses API login method to login to product and return API .Net object to client.

Issue is rest web service login in to product but object does not return to client.  Can rest service return .Net object ?

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely that a .NET object can be transferred via the API.

One way to do it is to serialize the object (convert it to JSON), with something like this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(obj);
```